# Problem this deploy django project to Heroku

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, heroku-cli

I try deploy django app to heroku and get errors:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to tandt-online-webchat.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/tandt-online-webchat.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: не удалось отправить некоторые ссылки в «https://git.heroku.com/tandt-online-webchat.git»
```

I done all what need:
git add .
git commit -m "releze heroku vers 1"
and when i do git push heroku master i get this error

I have all needs files: Procfile and requirements.txt
In Procfile i have: web: gunicorn web_chat.wsgi and to requirements.txt I input pip freeze, and i shure what i have gunicorn her.

What I do wrong?

Comment: may be trivial, but have you checked the Master Branch is not protected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common mistake is that you have misspelt your requirements.txt file. Another mistake that could have occurred is that your commits have gone very wrong. For this, reinitialise the git repository locally. Then make sure your requirements.txt file is being added. You can check this with

```
git status
```

If this still doesn't work please let me know.

Comment: thank you very mach, but I get a new error(, What can be wrong now?

Comment: Yes I have just answered the question to your new error. Please check it out. If it helped let me know .

Answer (score 0):

```
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        /tmp/build_61db1e8d/staticfiles
remote:        Post-processing 'css/base.css' failed!
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/tmp/build_61db1e8d/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
remote:            main()
remote:          File "/tmp/build_61db1e8d/manage.py", line 18, in main
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
remote:            self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
remote:            self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
remote:            output = self.handle(*args, **options)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 194, in handle
remote:            collected = self.collect()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 138, in collect
remote:            raise processed
remote:        whitenoise.storage.MissingFileError: The file 'css/web_chat_imgs/фон_д_к.png' could not be found with <whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x7f16d93bc3d0>.
remote:        The CSS file 'css/base.css' references a file which could not be found:
remote:          css/web_chat_imgs/фон_д_к.png
remote:        Please check the URL references in this CSS file, particularly any
remote:        relative paths which might be pointing to the wrong location.
remote: 
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote: 
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote: 
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote: 
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to tandt-online-webchat.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/tandt-online-webchat.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: не удалось отправить некоторые ссылки в «https://git.heroku.com/tandt-online-webchat.git»
```

Thank you, but I don't understend you realy completly. This is end of my setings.py file here sam thing wrong?

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR/ 'static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR/ 'asets',
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is another problem which a lot of people face. In your settings.py file,

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

This allows Heroku to store the static files in the folder 'static' on their git repository. You must already have static url in your settings folder. Otherwise:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/
```

Also, if you have any other problems, try to edit your original question rather than asking a new one as that sometimes extends the page too much.

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't know yet what here peple so fast to give answers

Comment: No problem! Did the solution work out for you? If yes you can mark my answer as the one which worked so if anyone else has a question similar to yours they can get the answer easily.

Comment: here sum thing wrrong this my setings?

Comment: Yes I have, please check the answer

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh I see the problem...I think. So heroku doesn't automatically serve static files, you have to add whitenoise to your settings.py. I will put the code for that here:

```
pip install whitenoise
```

Then, add whitenoise to your middleware classes

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # Simplified static file serving.
    # https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    ...
```

Then, add this at the bottom of your settings.py file. All this info is found here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

If all this doesn't work, read your error again. It says you are referencing a file that doesn't exist. You may be trying to load or access a file which doesn't exist at all. Check your file structure to make sure you aren't doing that.

Comment: Thank you very much againe, I 
already stuck this it problem. I don't now what I will do if not you!

Comment: Was I able to solve your issue? Were you able to deploy to Heroku successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, guy, but I'm starting to think  what fate itself don't wont to I deploying this app to heroku ️️

```
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: eee95ca439ed1b8c61ed275fd5d07488a2ff53d9
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version eee95ca439ed1b8c61ed275fd5d07488a2ff53d9
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to tandt-online-webchat.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/tandt-online-webchat.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: не удалось отправить некоторые ссылки в «https://git.heroku.com/tandt-online-webchat.git»
```

I done all what you are taping before and get a new error

Answer (score 0):

Delete the app from heroku.com and repeat then whole process again. It should work successfully this time.

Comment: yes, yes and yes! I done this I found misteak, my css file colled file what I don't have. I found it and now all work! Thank you very much for help!!

Comment: So happy for you! Good luck in the future!